# How do I run PHP unlink command that is stored in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, eval

can anyone help me to solve my query?
I want to execute php unlink command which is store in DB.
For example:

```
?php echo eval("?>".unlink('abc.txt')."<?") ?>
```

Please

Comment: You want to do what?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. There is no reason at all to have that in your database.

Comment: What is the text stored in the DB? Is it "unlink('abc.txt')"? I can't imagine a reason to do this...

Comment: What's your shoe size, and do your parents know what you're doing?

Comment: Actually i want to execute php which is store in DB.

Comment: My dear friend she is my daughter...

Comment: Ah ha ha ha, this _has_ to be a wind-up. :D

Comment: she is my doughter by the way...

Comment: Actually i want to execute php which is store in DB.

Comment: **Don't execute PHP pulled from a database. *Ever*.** If you think you need to do that, then you don't need to do that. What is the actual thing you are trying to do here? Why is code in the database?

Comment: Who said anything about your daughter?

Answer (score 1):

`?>` is a closing PHP tag, and `<?` is a short open PHP tag, so at a minimum, you have those backwards.

In your code,  you don't need these PHP tags at all.  They are meant for the parser, not for `eval()`, which is already in PHP mode.

The best thing to do is not store this sort of thing in your database.  I can't think of a single reason why you would put PHP code in your database values.  You should instead have that file name, and then run a `for` loop over the results to `unlink`.

Basically, your entire solution is broken.  You can start by removing those backwards PHP tags and it will work... but is that really what you want?  Probably not.

Comment: Actually i want to execute php which is store in DB. –

Comment: @AditiSharma You've said that, and I'm telling you that you can use `eval()` for that by not adding the PHP tags like you are trying to do in your code sample.  I'm also suggesting that there isn't any real-world situation I can think of where you need to do this.

Comment: ok thanks for your prompt help